# Spring: how to inject an inline list of strings using @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring

How do I inject a list of string values using the `@Value` annotation.  I'm using Spring 4.1.2.

I've tried:

```
@Value(value = "top, person, organizationalPerson, user")
private List<String> userObjectClasses
```

and then based on the [spring el documentation for inline lists](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-lists):

```
@Value(value = "{top, person, organizationalPerson, user}")
private List<String> userObjectClasses
```

These attempts only inject a string literal of the value given as the only element in the list.

**EDIT**

In this case, I'd like to be able to simply hard-code the values rather than read from a property file.  This approach seems a little less smelly than:

```
private List<String> userObjectClasses = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user"});
```

In the past, I've used spring's XML configuration to wire up beans, and in that case I could do (assuming the bean had a public setter for the `userObjectClasses` property):

```
<property value="userObjectClass">
  <list>
    <value>top</value>
    <value>person</value>
    <value>organizationalPerson</value>
    <value>user</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

Is there an analog to this when using annotation based configuration?

Comment: The answer hasn't helped yet? If it helped - then you could mark the question as answered. BTW comment below also helps.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`list.of.strings=first,second,third` took from properties file for e.g.

Then using [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html):

```
 @Value("#{'${list.of.strings}'.split(',')}") 
 private List<String> list;
```

**EDIT**

Then I don't think that you need to use annotation for such type of tasks. You could do all work just like you've menitioned or in the [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) in order to initialize some fields.

Comment: The spring convertion service will perform the split for you if your reference is an `array` or `Collection`, so you don't need that ugly expression: just `@Value("${list.of.strings}")`

Comment: @CostiCiudatu how does it know which delimiter to split on? does this only work for a `,`?

Comment: @ErinDrummond It uses [StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#commaDelimitedListToStringArray-java.lang.String-) internally; so yes, it relies on the comma-separated format.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu how to enable spring convertion service? not working for me by default. spring4