# How to inject a Map using the @Value Spring Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, spring-annotations

How can I inject values into a Map from the properties file using the @Value annotation in Spring?

My Spring Java class is and I tried using the $, but got the following error message:

> Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map Test.standard; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'com.test.standard' in string value "${com.test.standard}"

```
@ConfigurationProperty("com.hello.foo")
public class Test {

   @Value("${com.test.standard}")
   private Map<String,Pattern> standard = new LinkedHashMap<String,Pattern>

   private String enabled;

}
```

I have the following properties in a .properties file

```
com.test.standard.name1=Pattern1
com.test.standard.name2=Pattern2
com.test.standard.name3=Pattern3
com.hello.foo.enabled=true
```

Comment: You will need to use spring expression language. A similar question which used list (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390363/spring-how-to-inject-an-inline-list-of-strings-using-value-annotation). I am not sure you can do what you want out of the box. This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369458/how-to-fill-hashmap-from-java-property-file-with-spring-value is a bit more to your point. Uses a custom property mapper

Comment: What exactly do you want in your map? It seems you also expect some type converstion to a `Pattern`? What kind of `Pattern` class is that?

Comment: @Erlandsson this is a RegEx pattern, we will define valid regex pattern strings in the value

Comment: @LaurentuiL uin Spring boot, i am able to directly inject a map if the map matches the prefix described at class level but,my problem is the prefix at class level and this attribute level is different

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe Spring Boot supports loading properties maps out of the box with [@ConfigurationProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml) annotation.

According that docs you can load properties:

```
my.servers[0]=dev.bar.com
my.servers[1]=foo.bar.com
```

into bean like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class Config {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }
}
```

I used @ConfigurationProperties feature before, but without loading into map. You need to use [@EnableConfigurationProperties annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) to enable this feature.

Cool stuff about this feature is that you can [validate your properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation).

Comment: yes but, my problem is.. The Test class has its own @ConfigurationProperties prefix. So i want to use a diff prefix for this member variable alone . how can i do that ?

Comment: hmm, I missed that. So I would create separate two beans with @ConfiguraitonProperties annotation and autowire them into test class.

Comment: may have worked for the OP, but question didn't specify boot, and this problem doesn't work for general Spring, without boot.

Comment: the question is how to inject to a map using @Value annotation, but you are telling all sort of things rather than giving the answer to the question. Alternatives are okay but please stick to the answer as well

Answer (score 199):

You can inject values into a Map from the properties file using the `@Value` annotation like this.

The property in the properties file.

```
propertyname={key1:'value1',key2:'value2',....}
```

In your code.

```
@Value("#{${propertyname}}")  private Map<String,String> propertyname;
```

Note the hashtag as part of the annotation.

Comment: values must be quotes, else I get a `SpelEvaluationException`

Comment: How to set default value if the property is absent to prevent exception occurred?

Comment: If you want to use strings with whitespaces ( e.g _USB Camera 0xfd120000046d0819_ ) as keys, use single quotes as for values.

Comment: what if there's a `:` in the key?

Comment: Also seems to do type conversions e.g.: `@Value("#{${double.map}}") final Map<String, Double> doubleMap`

Comment: How to set default value ?

Comment: How to specify the same in a yml file

Comment: @MukulAnand in yaml it looks like this
`propertyname : >
       {
          key1:'value',
          key2:'value'
       }`

Sorry, I'm not able to format the linebreaks correct

Comment: _"Note the hashtag as part of the annotation..."_

Comment: Is it actually possible to do this?  I'm trying to use SPeL in code to do the same thing, but it just says "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]".

Comment: pattern "propertyname: {key1:'value1',key2:'value2',....}" does not work when injecting map from .yaml :  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder

Comment: What if value has SpEL expression with `'`? :(

Comment: **Be aware**, this isn't the same as using `propertyname.key1=...` and `propertyname.key2=...`. In stead, it uses a single property called `propertyname`. The equivalent in **YAML** is to **treat it as a string** as well and by **wrapping it in quotes**, such as: `"{key1:'value1',key2:'value2',....}"`. For more infor, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59210260/1915448).

Comment: @MikeD3ViDTyson - Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899860/spring-spel-expression-language-to-create-map-of-string-and-custom-object ?

Comment: Thank you for answering the actual question that was asked!!! The chosen answer may have been what the OP wanted to know. But, this answer actually answered the question THAT WAS ASKED!! Huge help!!! Thanks!

Comment: you can set the default value like this for an empty map: @Value("#{${tomcat.oleaconfig:{:}}}")

Comment: how about Map<String, List<String>>? Is this possible?

Comment: Is injecting Linkedhashmap possible ?

Comment: I tried  to inject   @Value("#{${x.y.z.Toggles}}")
    private Map<String, Boolean> Toggles; but got: exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)' can u plz help me?

Answer (score 21):

I had a simple code for Spring Cloud Config

like this:

In application.properties

> spring.data.mongodb.db1=mongodb://test@test1.com
>
> spring.data.mongodb.db2=mongodb://test@test2.com

### read

```
@Bean(name = "mongoConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.mongodb")
public Map<String, Map<String, String>> mongoConfig() {
    return new HashMap();
}
```

### use

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "mongoConfig")
private Map<String, String> mongoConfig;

@Bean(name = "mongoTemplates")
public HashMap<String, MongoTemplate> mongoTemplateMap() throws UnknownHostException {
    HashMap<String, MongoTemplate> mongoTemplates = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String>> entry : mongoConfig.entrySet()) {
        String k = entry.getKey();
        String v = entry.getValue();
        MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(v)));
        mongoTemplates.put(k, template);
    }
    return mongoTemplates;
}
```

Comment: I think your definition for the bean mongoConfig is incorrect. The method should be defined like this.                                                                        
public Map<String, String> mongoConfig() {
    return new HashMap();
}

Comment: this is probably the most elegant way if you simply want to inject a map from application.yml

Answer (score 20):

You can inject `.properties` as a map in your class using `@Resource` annotation.

If you are working with **`XML based configuration`,** then add below bean in your spring configuration file:

```
 <bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
      <property name="location" value="classpath:your.properties"/>
 </bean>
```

**For, Annotation based:**

```
@Bean(name = "myProperties")
public static PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(
                "your.properties"));
        return bean;
}
```

Then you can pick them up in your application as a Map:

```
@Resource(name = "myProperties")
private Map<String, String> myProperties;
```

Comment: We have used Spring Cloud Config server to provide the configurations, hence class path approach might not work. And we don't use XMLs

Comment: @Arpit - Could you please guide me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899860/spring-spel-expression-language-to-create-map-of-string-and-custom-object?

Answer (score 20):

To get this working with YAML, do this:

```
property-name: '{
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2"
}'
```

Answer (score 18):

Following worked for me:

SpingBoot 2.1.7.RELEASE

YAML Property (Notice value sourrounded by single quotes)

```
property:
   name: '{"key1": false, "key2": false, "key3": true}'
```

In Java/Kotlin annotate field with (Notice use of #) (For java no need to escape '$' with '\')

```
@Value("#{\${property.name}}")
```

Comment: how to make proper fallback to empty map if property is not found? otherwise context won't be initialized.

Comment: it works five for application.yml

Answer (score 7):

Here is how we did it. 
Two sample classes as follow:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaConsumerProperties.class)
public class KafkaContainerConfig {

    @Autowired
    protected KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConsumerProperties.getKafkaConsumerConfig());
    }
...

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class KafkaConsumerProperties {
    protected Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerConfig = new HashMap<>();

    @ConfigurationProperties("kafkaConsumerConfig")
    public Map<String, Object> getKafkaConsumerConfig() {
        return (kafkaConsumerConfig);
    }
...
```

To provide the kafkaConsumer config from a properties file, you can use: mapname[key]=value

```
//application.properties
kafkaConsumerConfig[bootstrap.servers]=localhost:9092, localhost:9093, localhost:9094
kafkaConsumerConfig[group.id]=test-consumer-group-local
kafkaConsumerConfig[value.deserializer]=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
kafkaConsumerConfig[key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

To provide the kafkaConsumer config from a yaml file, you can use "[key]": value
In application.yml file:

```
kafkaConsumerConfig:
  "[bootstrap.servers]": localhost:9092, localhost:9093, localhost:9094
  "[group.id]": test-consumer-group-local
  "[value.deserializer]": org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  "[key.deserializer]": org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code.

Below code for `application.yml`

```
my:
  mapValues:
    dbData: '{
      "connectionURL": "http://tesst:3306",
        "userName": "myUser",
        "password": "password123"
    }'
```

to access these key and values using `@Value` annotation use below java code.

```
@Value("#{${my.mapValues.dbData}}")
private Map<String,String> dbValues;
```