# What is the correct use of the property map read from .yaml with @Value Spring Annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, yaml, spring-annotations

I have injected properties from the map read from some .yaml in Spring Boot application the following way:

```
@Value("#{${app.map}}")
private Map<String, String> indexesMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But neither

```
app:
    map: {Countries: 'countries.xlsx', CurrencyRates: 'rates.xlsx'} 
    //note values in single quotes  

nor
app:
    map: {Countries: "countries.xlsx", CurrencyRates: "rates.xlsx"}
```

(as explained at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

nor

```
app:
    map:
      "[Countries]": countries.xslx
      "[CurrencyRates]": rates.xlsx
```

(as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51751123/2566304)

works - I keep getting the message 'Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder'

At the same time this works:

```
@Value("#{{Countries: 'countries.xlsx', CurrencyRates: 'rates.xlsx'}}")
private Map<String, String> indexesMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But I'd like to externalize properties

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `@ConfigurationProperties`, as suggested in one of the answers from the question you linked:

```
@Bean(name="AppProps")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app.map")
public Map<String, String> appProps() {
    return new HashMap();
}
```

and then

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("AppProps")
private Map<String, String> props;
```

would work with the config

```
app:
  map:
    Countries: 'countries.xlsx'
    CurrencyRates: 'rates.xlsx'
```

EDIT: `@Value` annotation works as well, but you have to treat it as a String in YAML:

```
@Value("#{${app.map}}")
private Map<String, String> props;
```

and

```
app:
  map: "{Countries: 'countries.xlsx', CurrencyRates: 'rates.xlsx'}"
```

Note the quotes around the map value. Apparently Spring parses it out of a String in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option using the **Guava library**. It may be useful to someone or someone will improve it. The advantage is that it is quite flexible and concise and allows you to specify the **required types of values in the map**. But it requires that the input is a string, for example for the value:

```
app:
  map: "Countries: countries.xlsx, CurrencyRates: rates.xlsx"
```

the following expression is needed:

```java
    @Value("#{T(com.google.common.base.Splitter).on(', ').withKeyValueSeparator(': ').split('${app.map}')}")
    private Map<String, String> map;
```

the result will be obtained:

```java
map = {Collections$UnmodifiableMap@5183}  size = 2
 "Countries" -> "countries.xlsx"
 "CurrencyRates" -> "rates.xlsx"
```