# In spring, how to read a list of maps using @Value from yaml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I was able to read a single map like this:

```
@Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
private Map<String, String> valuesMap;
```

and a yml like this:

```
    valuesMap: 
          "{path:'/tmp/aaa',
             ext:'csv',
             ttl:60}"
```

using the solution described here [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715308/what-is-the-correct-use-of-the-property-map-read-from-yaml-with-value-spring-a) from stackoverflow.

Now I need to read an array/list of maps like  this [{path:/a,ext:csv,ttl:50}, {path:/b,ext:txt,ttl:30},...] using something like this:

```
@Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
private Map<String, String> valuesMap[];
```

or

```
@Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
private List<Map<String, String>> valuesMap;
```

Is this possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using:

```
@Value("#{${valuesMap}}")
private List<Map<String, String>> valuesMap;
```

and

```
    valuesMap: 
          "{{path:'/tmp/aaa',
             extension:'csv',
             ttl:60},
            {path:'/tmp/bbb',
             extension:'txt',
             ttl:40}}"
```

The synatx could be more friendly but it seams to work now.