# How does one convert application.properties to application.yml for maps

Tags: java, spring-boot, maps, yaml

I tried this, it doesn't work, where am I going wrong?

application.properties (works fine)

```
document-contact={name:'joe',email:'joe.bloggs@gmail.com'}
```

application.yml (doesn't work; stacktrace below)

```
document-contact:
  name: 'joe'
  email: 'joe.bloggs@gmail.com'
```

Java:

```
    @Value("#{${document-contact}}")
    private Map<String, String> contact;
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consolidatedSwaggerDocumentationController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'document-contact' in value "#{${document-contact}}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:403) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `application.yml` is not equivalent to the `application.properties` you're using.

Rather than reading separate properties, you only have a single property called `document-contract` (= `${document-contract}`), which contains the following **string**:

```java
"{name:'joe',email:'joe.bloggs@gmail.com'}"
```

To convert it to a `Map`, you're using [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). That's why you need both `#{...}` and `${...}`.

Your `application.yml` file on the other hand doesn't have a single property called `document-contract`, and thus, it doesn't work. If you want to do the same kind of thing within your YAML, it should be:

```
document-contract: "{name: 'joe', email: 'joe.bloggs@gmail.com'}"
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to use multiple YAML properties like you did, you should be aware that `@Value` doesn't support `Map` structures. In stead, you should be using `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private Map<String, String> documentContact;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

With `@ConfigurationProperties`, you would have to use a prefix though, so you should change your YAML structure to:

```
app:
  document-contact:
    name: joe
    email: joe.bloggs@gmail.com
```

For the reference, this would be the equivalent properties file:

```
app.document-contract.name=joe
app.document-contact.email=joe.bloggs@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 4):

you need use follow:

```
tes:
  maps:
    key1: 15
    key2: 2
```

and java code is:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tes")
public class MapTest {
    private Map<String, String> maps;
}
```

Comment: perfect! @Benson