# Spring MVC - Reading properties file using Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

> Values from .properties file could not read due to exception  (org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'genderOptions' cannot be found)

I have configured the property place holder. My property file is having two entries (M=MALE, F=FEMALE) I wanted to populate this as a list of options in checkbox while submitting the form.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/player")
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = 
"classpath:gender.properties")
public class PlayerController {

@Value("#{genderOptions}") 
public Map<String, String> genderOptions;

@RequestMapping("/playerForm")
public String showPlayerForm(Model model) {

    Player player = new Player();
    model.addAttribute("player", player);
    model.addAttribute("genderOptions", genderOptions);
    return "player-form";
}
```

Comment: Debug your application; in particular, examine what the value of the field is in your controller method.

Comment: are you using spring boot or plain spring mvc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691949/how-to-inject-a-map-using-the-value-spring-annotation

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC not Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use genderOptions as Map in the Controller, then first you need specify it in the form of key-value in `gender.properties` file.

`genderOptions = {M:'Male', F:'Female'}`

And while accessing it in the controller, you need to make following changes in order to let spring cast it in Map.

```
@Value("#{${genderOptions}}")
private Map<String, String> mapValues;
```

And if you need to get the value of a specific key in the Map, all you have to do is add the key's name in the expression:

```
@Value("#{${genderOptions}.M}")
private String maleKey;
```

Comment: >Its working. I'm getting the values from properties file after making changes as you suggested. But, I'm facing one more issue while displaying those options (read from propertied) in form.  '<form:label path="gender">
    <spring:message code="Gender:" />
   </form:label>
   <form:select path="gender"> 
    <form:options items="${genderOptions}" />
   </form:select> '

Comment: > Its working fine. <spring:message code="lable.gender" /> after adding this.. I got the expected output. Thanks for your input.