# How to use @ConfigurationProperties to get a value from a parameter passed to application.properties?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

I am using `Spring Boot` and `Java` and my `application.properties` file looks like this right now:

```
 germany.berlin.zipcode.10245=Friedrichshain
 germany.berlin.zipcode.14193=Charlottenburg
 germany.berlin.zipcode.10247=Neukolln
```

I am using `@ConfigurationProperties` to extract the values assigned in the properties in my code. More specifically I want to be able to give the zipcode number(e.g. 10245) in a method and it should return the place (Friedrichshain in that case). What I have tried so far:

**Properties Config class**

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AddressConfig.class)
public class PropertiesConfig {

}
```

**AddressConfig class**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "germany.berlin")
public class AddressConfig {

    private Map<Integer, String> zipCode;

    public String getAreaForzipCode(int code) {
        return zipCode.get(code);
    }

}
```

But when I do:

```
getAreaForzipCode(10245)
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

Does anyone know whats the proper way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inject a Map using the @Value Spring Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691949/how-to-inject-a-map-using-the-value-spring-annotation) (I know it uses `@Value`, but the answer is the same I think.)

Comment: The annotation `@Configuration` is missing on your `PropertiesConfig` class.

Comment: @adarsh didnt work

Comment: @hispanicprogrammer that's weird. The map should get initialized with values. In fact, I quickly did a set up on my machine and it works. What is the Spring Boot version you're using? I tried with `2.2.6.RELEASE`. If you don't have it already, try adding the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration class valid usage example:

```java
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

    @Bean
    MyComponent myComponent(final AddressConfig config) {
        final String area = config.getAreaForzipCode(10245); // Friedrichshain
        return new MyComponent(area);
    }
}
```