# Is there a way to move a static map to configuration in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Given a class like:

```
@Component
public class ValueHelper {

    private static Map<Integer, Number> valuesMap;
    static {
        valuesMap = new HashMap<>();
        valuesMap.put(11, Short.parseShort("0"));
        valuesMap.put(12, Integer.valueOf(0));
        valuesMap.put(21, Float.NaN);
        valuesMap.put(22, Double.NaN);
        valuesMap.put(14, Long.valueOf(0L));
    }

    public Number getFillValueForType(Integer key) {
        Number number = valuesMap.get(key);
        return number;
    }
}
```

I don't like this static initialisation and wanted to know if there is a better way to do it in Spring Boot using the `application.properties`. I've seen that there is basic support for maps via `application.properties` but it doesn't seem complex enough to handle objects in this way?

If not possible via properties, maybe there is a way to avoid this static initialisation in any case.

Thanks

Comment: Try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794304/3432678

Comment: I've read that. but it doesn't help. It is OK if the values in the map are of the same type or simple strings.

Answer (score 2):

Using @ConfigurationProperties you can inject them into `Map<Integer,Number>`

```
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
@Data
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    private Map<String,Number> values;

    public Number getFillValueForType(Integer key) {
        Number number = values.get(key);
        return number;
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
test:
  values:
    11: 0
    12: 0
    21: 0
    22: 0
    14: 0
```