# How to convert data from properties file and set to List property (with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer)?

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have an entity:

```
public class Auditorium {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer numberOfSeats;
    private List<String> vipSeats;

    public Auditorium(String name, Integer numberOfSeats, List<String> vipSeats) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
        this.vipSeats = vipSeats;
    }
```

and I want to create `Auditorium` instance from property file, like:

```
auditorium1.name=yellow hall
auditorium1.number-of-seats=150
auditorium1.vip-seats=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

I have few different files and I want to create different `Auditorium` beans.

Here is snippet from `spring.xml`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:auditorium1.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:auditorium2.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:auditorium3.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="systemPropertiesMode">
        <util:constant
                static-field="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<util:list id="auditorium1" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value></value>
</util:list>

<util:list>
    <bean class="net.lelyak.edu.entity.Auditorium"
          p:name="${auditorium1.name}" p:numberOfSeats="${auditorium1.number-of-seats}" p:vipSeats="${auditorium1.vip-seats}"/>
</util:list>
```

But Iam getting an error:

[image]

Because `No matching constructor found`.

And much better will have `List<Integer> vipSeats`. Is it possible at this situation?

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 aspects here to be covered, so let's take them one at a time:

1)IJ (short for IntelliJ Idea) is suggesting that according to your bean declaration, Spring will be trying to invoke a no-arg constructor, which clearly does not exist since you've defined `public Auditorium(String name, Integer numberOfSeats, List<String> vipSeats)`.

Thus you can configure it to call the above mentioned constructor passing the correct arguments, as per the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators):

```xml
<bean class="com.example.Auditorium">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="${auditorium1.name}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="numberOfSeats" value="${auditorium1.number-of-seats}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="vipSeats" value="${auditorium1.vip-seats}"/>
</bean>
```

Apart from this, no special handling is required for Spring to inject your list, as you can see in the log snippet below, outputted by a simple `toString()` IJ auto-generated method:

```
16:13:56.569 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'com.example.Auditorium#0'
16:13:56.601 [main] DEBUG com.example.Auditorium - Auditorium{id=null, name='yellow hall', numberOfSeats=150, vipSeats=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
```

---

2) I see you're trying to use the [p-namespace](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-p-namespace) to pass arguments to your constructor, however that's used to set properties/attribute after bean instantiation. You can use the [c-namespace](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-c-namespace) to achieve the same effect as using the `<constructor-arg>` tag and be less verbose (please note that as per the spring docs, p & c namespaces the are not defined in an XSD file and exist only in the core of Spring):

```xml
<beans ...
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       ...>

    <bean id="myAuditorium" class="com.example.Auditorium" c:name="${auditorium1.name}" c:numberOfSeats="${auditorium1.number-of-seats}" c:vipSeats="${auditorium1.vip-seats}"/>
```

And again the log snippet, generated for both the definitions this time:

```
16:26:52.258 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'com.example.Auditorium#0'
16:26:52.287 [main] DEBUG com.example.Auditorium - Auditorium{id=null, name='yellow hall', numberOfSeats=150, vipSeats=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
...
16:26:52.287 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'com.example.Auditorium#1'
16:26:52.288 [main] DEBUG com.example.Auditorium - Auditorium{id=null, name='yellow hall', numberOfSeats=150, vipSeats=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
```

---

**Note:** Depending on the Spring version that you are using & your needs, it may be worth also checking [annotation-based configs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config). It may be a personal preference, but I find them cleaner and easier to maintain, and IJ has excellent Spring support for both types of config.

---

**Special request update:** Brief annotation introduction

First of all it depends on your project's setup, whether you use *basic* Spring Core or Spring Boot as well, etc. For this introduction: I'll just start from where you are at this point:

Enable component scanning so Spring can discover and create your components, services, etc

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="...
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
```

Then change our class. If you don't need to do anything else in your constructor then we can simply remove it and annotate the fields. **When annotating fields** please take into consideration that Spring will be able to populate them only after instantiating the beans, hence using then in a constructor will most likly result in a NPE. In such cases you can use `@PostConstruct`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class Auditorium {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Auditorium.class);
    private Integer id;

    @Value("${auditorium1.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("${auditorium1.number-of-seats}")
    private Integer numberOfSeats;

    @Value("${auditorium1.vip-seats}")
    private List<String> vipSeats;

    @PostConstruct
    private void doAfterConstruction() {
        log.debug(this.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Auditorium{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", numberOfSeats=" + numberOfSeats +
                ", vipSeats=" + vipSeats +
                '}';
    }
}
```

As you'll see in the log, Spring will instantiate the bean, then inject the values for its fields and eventually the post-processors will call the `@PostConstruct` annotated method:

```
12:20:34.037 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'auditorium'
12:20:34.038 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'auditorium'
12:20:34.045 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Found init method on class [com.example.Auditorium]: private void com.example.Auditorium.doAfterConstruction()
12:20:34.045 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Registered init method on class [com.example.Auditorium]: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement@1ec4fbf0
12:20:34.060 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [com.example.Auditorium]: AutowiredFieldElement for private java.lang.String com.example.Auditorium.name
12:20:34.060 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [com.example.Auditorium]: AutowiredFieldElement for private java.lang.Integer com.example.Auditorium.numberOfSeats
12:20:34.060 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Registered injected element on class [com.example.Auditorium]: AutowiredFieldElement for private java.util.List com.example.Auditorium.vipSeats
12:20:34.060 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'auditorium' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:20:34.062 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'auditorium': AutowiredFieldElement for private java.lang.String com.example.Auditorium.name
12:20:34.067 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'auditorium': AutowiredFieldElement for private java.lang.Integer com.example.Auditorium.numberOfSeats
12:20:34.072 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.annotation.InjectionMetadata - Processing injected element of bean 'auditorium': AutowiredFieldElement for private java.util.List com.example.Auditorium.vipSeats
12:20:34.084 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Invoking init method on bean 'auditorium': private void com.example.Auditorium.doAfterConstruction()
12:20:34.085 [main] DEBUG com.example.Auditorium - Auditorium{id=null, name='yellow hall', numberOfSeats=150, vipSeats=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
12:20:34.094 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'auditorium'
```

Or if you'd like to keep your constructor, we'll just mark it as `@Autowired` and annotate the parameters as well:

```
@Component
public class Auditorium {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Auditorium.class);
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer numberOfSeats;
    private List<String> vipSeats;

    @Autowired
    public Auditorium(@Value("${auditorium1.name}") String name,
                      @Value("${auditorium1.number-of-seats}") Integer numberOfSeats,
                      @Value("${auditorium1.vip-seats}") List<String> vipSeats) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats;
        this.vipSeats = vipSeats;
        log.debug(this.toString());
    }
}
```

And the log, which is simpler this time

```
12:29:09.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'auditorium'
12:29:09.492 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'auditorium'
12:29:09.525 [main] DEBUG com.example.Auditorium - Auditorium{id=null, name='yellow hall', numberOfSeats=150, vipSeats=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
12:29:09.526 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'auditorium' to allow for resolving potential circular references
12:29:09.548 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'auditorium'
```

Comment: What does `IJ` mean?

Comment: @nazar_art Good point. It's short for IntelliJ Idea, I recognized the theme from the XML definition screenshot. I'll just update the answer to make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example how to use `Annotation approach` here. It will be very useful for me, coz I am using `Spring 3.2.13.

Comment: @nazar_art this is to broad a subject to be covered on SO. Take a look at the [spring doc link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) I had provided and other [similar tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/). They're better suited for the job and if you have trouble, then you'll surely find answers on SO. But just to get you started I added a short sample based on your original project. Cheers

Comment: do you know how to save `vipSeats` exactly like Set. Because now it is saved like one string `1,2,3,4,5`?

Comment: @nazar_art I apologise, it looks like some processing is indeed required, and the simplest solution seems to be SpEL (spring expression language), something along the lines of `"#{'${list.of.strings}'.split(',')}"`. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390363/spring-how-to-inject-an-inline-list-of-strings-using-value-annotation) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value)

Comment: How can I configure 3 different auditories if I have to set only specific one to my entity? Like `@Value("${auditorium1.name}") private String name;`

Comment: @nazar_art The simplest solution which comes to mind is to define your own `@Configuration` with 3 different methods for creating `@Bean`. The spring docs have [a short intro](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-bean-annotation) and a more [detailed section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-bean-annotation) on this matter.

Comment: I have tried, and finally asked one more question - [How to configure Spring configuration for List of Beans from different property files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443942/how-to-configure-spring-configuration-for-list-of-beans-from-different-property)